# SQL Consolidate values based on date and add result column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table containing the following data (date is an INT data type), it consists of `Object`s of which each one has two `Type`s that can be set to either `Not modifiable` or `Modifiable` for a certain time range:

```
Object Type StatusOld   StatusNew   Date
/1BCDWB/    2    Not modifiable Modifiable  20011003
HOME    1    Not modifiable Modifiable  20011003
/1BCDWB/    2    Modifiable Not modifiable  20011003
HOME    1    Modifiable Not modifiable  20011003
/0CUST/ 2    Not modifiable Modifiable  20011003
/0SAP/  2    Not modifiable Modifiable  20011003
/0SAP/  2    Modifiable Not modifiable  20011003
/1BCABA/    2    Not modifiable Modifiable  20011003
/1BCABA/    2    Modifiable Not modifiable  20011003
/0CUST/ 2    Not modifiable Modifiable  20011003
/0SAP/  2    Not modifiable Modifiable  20011003
/1BCABA/    2    Not modifiable Modifiable  20011003
/1BCDWB/    2    Not modifiable Modifiable  20011003
/0CUST/ 2    Modifiable Not modifiable  20011003
/0SAP/  2    Modifiable Not modifiable  20011003
/1BCABA/    2    Modifiable Not modifiable  20011003
/1BCDWB/    2    Modifiable Not modifiable  20011003
/0CUST/ 2    Modifiable Not modifiable  20011210
/1BCDWB/    2    Modifiable Not modifiable  20011210
HOME    1    Modifiable Not modifiable  20011210
/0CUST/ 2    Not modifiable Modifiable  20011210
/1BCDWB/    2    Not modifiable Modifiable  20011210
HOME    1    Not modifiable Modifiable  20011210
HOME    1    Not modifiable Modifiable  20020211
```

then I have a table with the relevant time ranges I need to check for those values:

```
start_date end_date
20000610 20000610
20000611 20011002
```

In the end result, I need a simple `Yes` or `No` for the above time range if both `Type` 1 and 2 of one `Object` have been set to `Modifiable` during that time:

```
SystemModifiable start_date end_date
No 20000610 20000610
No 20000611 20011002
```

So I was thinking of a CTE case statement like this:

```
Case
    When ((Type=1 And StatusNew=Modifiable) And (Type=2 And StatusNew=Modifiable)) And -- For each date range-- Then 'Yes'
    Else 'No'
End As SystemModifiable
```

Maybe this pseudocode will help to understand it better. For yes, as a result, the following condition needs to be met:

```
IF (Type=1 AND StatusNew=modifiable AND
Type=2 AND StatusNew=modifiable) SET SystemModifiable to 'Yes'
ELSE SET SystemModifiable to 'No'
```

I appreciate your help, if you have questions let me know.

Comment: What would be the expected reult, if - within the analyzed timespan - an ID is first set to modifiable and then back to not modifiable? Do you want to consider the last change per ID within the timespan?

Comment: @Tyron78 I have added a column to my question and added some explanation, I think that should explain it better?

Comment: @goatw . . . I don't understand your results.  Where is the object represented?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sorry, let me try to explain: Each object exists two times, once with type 1 and once with type 2. Now in order for my result to be 'yes' one type 1 and one type 2 of any object in that time frame need to be set to modifiable. So the object really doesn't matter, since I only need to look for two modifiable entrys of which one is type 1 and one is type to. I will add a explaination to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query (comments are inline):

```
select mt.Object, ts.start_date, ts.end_date,
       -- since we have only type 1 or 2, this check will suffice to determine whether 1 and 2 type were included
       case when count(distinct Type) = 2 then 'Yes' else 'No' end
from MyTable mt
right join Timespans ts on mt.Date between ts.start_date and ts.end_date
-- here we want only those records, that were changed to modifiable and only with Type 1 or 2
where mt.Type in (1, 2) and
      mt.StatusNew = 'Modifiable'
      -- to include timespans, which don't have any matching entry
      or (mt.type is null and mt.Object is null)
-- Group by timespan and by object
group by mt.Object, ts.start_date, ts.end_date
```

[Here's demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eeec6/6)

**FURTHER NOTE** Above query will give you results per timespan and per object (as you can see in the demo), to get simple answer per period, just group again by timespan checking if there is any `Yes` within a group :)

Comment: So, this query gives the timespan, where the system is modifiable - as far as I understood the OP, the result should display each Timespan with the info, if modifiable or not... no?

Comment: @Tyron78 This will give result including every timespan and will indicate whether it's `modifiable` or not.

Comment: I just tested it with two timespans, of which one is modifiable, but the result shows only one row - can you please check? Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bf9c5f/28/1

Comment: @Tyron78 Your table doesn't have `Type` or `Object` column

Comment: @Tyron78 It was due to lack entries in first timespan you specified, corrected that. Also fixed you fiddle :) Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Yes, I created it before this change of the OP. Type should be same as "ID". Considering I have no object, I'd expect two rows since I have two timespans

Comment: Could you please post the new fiddle link? Each change results in a new link :) Thanks for fixing

Comment: @Tyron78 It's in the answer

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answers. I think that @MichałTurczyn your first query solves my problem since in the result the object doesn't matter, it only matters whether there has been a type 1 and a type 2 both set to modifiable in one period.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a query prior to your latest change - however, should be modifiable quite easy I'd guess:

First of all I build a cte with the timespans and all used IDs (in your case only 1 and 2). Basing on this I evaluate the latest status change of the selected ID in the current timespan. Basing on this I perform a pivot operation in order to get the status of IDs 1 and 2 in one row per timespan. This can then be queried - as you mentioned - with a case statement. Here the example code:

```
WITH cteTimeSpan AS (
  SELECT T3.ID, T2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start_date) rn
    FROM T2
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM T1) AS T3
),
cteStatChanges AS(
  SELECT ts.ID, ts.rn, ts.start_date, ts.end_date, t1.StatusNew, T1.[Date], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ts.rn, ts.ID ORDER BY start_date DESC) rn2
    FROM cteTimeSpan AS ts
    LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.[Date] >= ts.start_date AND T1.[Date] <= ts.end_date
),
cteFilter AS(
  SELECT csc.ID, csc.start_date, csc.end_date, csc.StatusNew
    FROM cteStatChanges csc
    WHERE rn2 = 1
),
ctePiv AS(
  SELECT start_date, end_date, [1], [2]
    FROM cteFilter
  PIVOT (
    MAX(StatusNew)
    FOR ID IN ([1], [2])
  ) piv
)
SELECT p.start_date, p.end_date, CASE WHEN ISNULL([1], N'Not Modifiable') = N'Modifiable' AND ISNULL([2], N'Not Modifiable') = N'Modifiable' THEN N'yes' ELSE N'no' END AS SystemModifiable
  FROM ctePiv p
```

See fiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bf9c5f/24/1

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select r.start_date, r.end_date, t.object,
       (case when count(distinct type) = 2 then 'Yes' else 'No' end)
from ranges r join
     t
     on t.date between r.start_date and r.end_date
where StatusNew = 'Modifiable' and
      type in (1, 2)
group by t.object;
```

Comment: This will group independently of timespans.